# Error while installing tensorflowjs node | Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, npm, npm-install, tensorflow.js

I was trying to install `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` and i am getting this error. `Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` is there any way to fix this?

here is the completely log:

```js
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-3.7.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.4
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.3.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7\tfjs_binding.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.7.0/CPU-windows-3.7.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.7.0/CPU-windows-3.7.0.zip
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.7.0 and node@15.3.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v7/3.7.0/CPU-windows-3.7.0.zip
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.3.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for Node-API version 8
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.3.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:302:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:200:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:266:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:316:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:328:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:275:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:467:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=E:\\AI\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v7\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=E:\\AI\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v7" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=7" "--node_napi_label=napi-v7"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=7 --node_napi_label=napi-v7' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\AI\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1055:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\AI\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd E:\AI\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.4
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR!
npm ERR! * Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install any version of python2.x or python3.x for running TensorFlow in your system.